# Ninject form injection and Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ninject

I have Set Form, inside this form I inject some another set form

```
  public partial class ServicePriceBlockSetForm : RibbonForm
   {

    [Inject]
    private OtherServiceSetForm OtherServiceSetForm { get; set; }

    public ServicePriceBlockSetForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   ...
   }
```

When I call this form by button click, first time form opened and everything is OK. When I close and try open this form again I get:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

Form registred in Ninject container like this.

```
_kernel.Bind<ServicePriceBlockSetForm>().ToSelf();
_kernel.Bind<OtherServiceSetForm>().ToSelf();
```

What can I do with this error?

Comment: You first will need to find out which object is disposed. To do that you'll have to use the exception stacktrace and navigate in the code.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886198/program-crash-with-system-objectdisposedexception

Comment: Disposed object are this injected form OtherServiceSetForm. When I close this form, then this form dispose.

Comment: With the code you've posted, i can tan tell with a 100% guarantee, that Ninject is not disposing the form. But i believe what you've posted here may digress from what you've actually have. So you'll have to look for the issue somewhere else or post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve